# npm start error with create-react-app with react script version : "4.0.1"

Tags: reactjs

i create a react app it installs like normal i use the npx command for that. It is latest version of react "17.0.1", and react-scripts 4.0.1 in window 10.
find the error log.

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~prestart: react-complete-guide@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~start: react-complete-guide@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Our Project\Owendprojects\Orbit\hemant lab\lab\React\react-complete-guide\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\WDMS\python-support\Python36_64;C:\WDMS\python-support\Python36_64\Scripts;C:\WDMS\python-support\Python36_64\DLLs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\vihana\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\vihana\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Micro;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\vihana\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\vihana\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\vihana\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\vihana\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\Our Project\Owendprojects\Orbit\hemant lab\lab\React\react-complete-guide
10 silly lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle react-complete-guide@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid react-complete-guide@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Our Project\Owendprojects\Orbit\hemant lab\lab\React\react-complete-guide
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.15.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json file have
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",

Comment: it says something about your react start script, make sure that is in your package.json. It also says your using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1, you might try updating node fully and reinitializing npx create-react-app

Comment: If it's not working, try to uninstall the `node_modules` folder and install again. Sound strange but it happens to me sometimes that first time install fail but remove and install again it works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package.json looks like this for your client?

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working have same like stracture in package.json file

Comment: what does your root directory and file structure look like? And are you cd'ing in the same directory that your react-script start is?